# How can I configure Spring Security 5 OAuth correctly with Vue.js?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We are building a Web Application with Spring Boot and Vue.js. Currently we are migrating from Security OAuth 2.x to Spring Security 5.2.x and having issues with the Oauth2 flow.

Below is the security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(new StaticAllowFromStrategy(location)));

        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login", "/static/**","/", "/actuator/prometheus")
          .permitAll()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .oauth2Login();


    }

    private static List<String> clients = Arrays.asList("authnext");

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        List<ClientRegistration> registrations = clients.stream()
          .map(c -> getRegistration(c))
          .filter(registration -> registration != null)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
    }


    private ClientRegistration getRegistration(String client) {


        if (client.equals("authnext")) {

            return AuthNextOAuth2Provider.AUTHNEXT.getBuilder(client, "https://baseurl/auth/oauth2/realms/root/realms/intranetb2x/authorize",
                    "https://baseurl/auth/oauth2/realms/root/realms/intranetb2x/tokeninfo",
                    "https://baseurl/auth/oauth2/realms/root/realms/intranetb2x/userinfo")
                    .clientId("ID")
                    .clientSecret("SECRET")
                    .build();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {

        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(
          clientRegistrationRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> authorizationRequestRepository() {

        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }


}
```

Furthermore we have the following AuthNextOAuth2Provider:

```
public enum AuthNextOAuth2Provider {

    AUTHNEXT {
        @Override
        public Builder getBuilder(String registrationId,String authUri,String tokenUri, String userInfoUri) {
            ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder(registrationId, ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC,DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL);

            builder.scope("openid", "profile", "b2xroles");
            builder.authorizationUri(authUri);
            builder.tokenUri(tokenUri);
            builder.userInfoUri(userInfoUri);
            builder.userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB);
            builder.clientName("authnext");
            return builder;
        }
    };
    private static final String DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "{baseUrl}/login";

    protected final ClientRegistration.Builder getBuilder(String registrationId, ClientAuthenticationMethod method,
            String redirectUri) {
        ClientRegistration.Builder builder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId);
        builder.clientAuthenticationMethod(method);
        builder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
        builder.redirectUriTemplate(redirectUri);
        return builder;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new
     * {@link org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration.Builder
     * ClientRegistration.Builder} pre-configured with provider defaults.
     * 
     * @param registrationId the registration-id used with the new builder
     * @return a builder instance
     */
    public abstract ClientRegistration.Builder getBuilder(
            String registrationId,
            String authUri,
            String tokenUri,
            String userInfoUri
    );

}
```

The problem is the redirect isn't working correctly. We can be correctly directed to the auth server and login there but when redirected back to the spring application we get a 404 error.

How it works is as follows. We have a Spring Boot application which lives at /. I want to allow all requests to the / /login und /static/** so that the vue.js resources are correctly served. The vue.js application is calling an backend endpoint status to check if the broswer is currently authenticated. If this is not the case then the user is redirected to the Oauth2 auth server as follows:

```
 checkLoggedIn: function() {
  AXIOS({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/status",
    responseType: "blob"
  })
    .then(response => {

      var element = document.getElementById("step1");
      element.classList.add("step-active");
      document.getElementById("lock1").style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("lock2").style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("lock3").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("lock4").style.visibility = "hidden";
      this.connect();

    })
    .catch(error => {

            if(typeof error.response === 'undefined'){
                var localStorage = window.localStorage;
                window.localStorage.setItem('route', JSON.stringify(this.$route));  
                window.location.href = "/login";
            }else if(error.response.status===403){
                 this.$parent.upload = false;
                 this.$parent.uploadResult = false;
                 this.$parent.checkData = false;
                 this.$parent.approveData = false;
                 this.$parent.checkout = false;
                 this.$parent.unauthorized=true; 

            }
    });
}},
```

Forcing the browser to visit /login seems to begin the authentication workflow correctly but on the way back there is a problem with the following request:

[image: Failed Redirect back to spring]

How can I configure the login flow correctly. It also seems to create some endpoints in the backend of the form:

oauth2/authorization/authnext

What is this and is it necessary. With Spring OAuth2 we just used @EnableOauth2Sso and everything just worked.

Here are the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${oauth-auto.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.44</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.44</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId> <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId> 
        <version>1.1.44</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId> 
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId> <version>1.1.44</version> </dependency> -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-metrics</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_common</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please share your dependencies as well.

Comment: Added the dependencies.

Comment: To answer one of your questions, `/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}` is required because that is what will ultimately start the authorization code grant flow. There is more info in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#initiating-the-authorization-request